# visibility of buttons and layout

Tags: android

I have 10*3 buttons on my screen. When I click a button, I want it to be unvisible, so I do :
`arg0.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

But whenever the button is gone, the buttons change their size.
For example, if at the begining every button took 1/3 of a row, now when a button is gone the other buttons in the row get wider..

Is there a way to make them not change their size when a button is removed?

Answer (score 7):

Use [View.INVISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE). Using GONE makes it as if it wasn't there (so it no longer takes up space). Invisible just makes it disappear.